# android activity order, want only one instance of current activity, instead of clearing stack

Tags: android, android-activity, single-instance, launchmode

singleTask and singleInstance alone are not the answer.

I have activities in a stack   `... n, n+1, n+2`

elements in `n+2` can open `n+1`

this creates stack

`... n, n+1, n+2, n+1`

I want it to create stack

`... n, n+2, n+1` , where `n+1` is moved to the top of stack

singleTask creates this stack

`... n, n+1`

and singleInstance creates this stack

`n+1` where all previous activities are closed.

neither of which I want.

is there any launch mode I can use?

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` only makes it so that this activity isn't loaded again from scratch, but doesn't clear the duplicate activity in history, maybe there is a combination of flags I can use? or I can possibly locate that activity in the index of the activity stack and remove it if it isn't the most recent activity ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.
>   For example, consider a task consisting of four activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the history stack, with this resulting order: A, C, D, B. This flag will be ignored if FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is also specified.

Comment: yes, this is behaving strangely. In this example, my activity A is killed for some reason

Comment: removing reorder_to_front keeps all my activities alive.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to your intent. Without that flag, your scenario creates a stack as follow: (starting Activity A, A start B, and then B again start A)

```
TaskRecord{41ab0370 #23 A com.example.testproject U 0}
  Run #7: ActivityRecord{41c655a8 u0 com.example.testproject/.MainActivity}
  Run #6: ActivityRecord{41d378d0 u0 com.example.testproject/.SecondActivity}
  Run #5: ActivityRecord{41bf99b8 u0 com.example.testproject/.MainActivity}
```

But using the flag, without any specific launch mode, you will get the following stack, which I assume it's the one you need:

```
TaskRecord{41d8a838 #25 A com.example.testproject U 0}
  Run #6: ActivityRecord{41d89590 u0 com.example.testproject/.MainActivity}
  Run #5: ActivityRecord{41c52b80 u0 com.example.testproject/.SecondActivity}
```